# Work done in Polarizing a Piezoelectric

Tags: thermodynamics, piezoelectric

Work Done by a conservative force in a complete cycle is zero. Does that mean the the Ferroelectric Hysteresis loop represents zero work done ? 
So according to 1st Law of Thermodynamics, the Energy Stored in the system (area enclosed by curve) completely manifests as Heat ?